# How to achive STRING_AGG in RelNode?

Tags: sql, apache-calcite

I have a query where I want to concat all the rows with a delimiter `,`. I can easily achieve this in sql using `STRING_AGG`. How to create a relNode for the following query ?

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(col1, col2, col3), ',')
FROM table;
```

Is there a single `SqlStdOperator` which does this ?

If not, what combinations of `SqlStdOperator`(s) in `builder.call(..., RexNode... rexNodes)` to use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalent of STRING_AGG is `SqlStdOperator.LISTAGG`

```
builder
.scan("table")
.project(
    builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.LISTAGG,
        builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.CONCAT,
            builder.field("col1"),
            builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.CONCAT,
                builder.field("col2"),
                builder.field("col3")
            )
        ),
        builder.literal(",")
    )
)
.build()
```